# "IndexError: list index out of range" in model.fit() method when using Dataset in Tensorflow Keras classifier

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm new in TensorFlow and I'm trying to create a classifier using Keras. My training data is spitted into two files: 
- one with training examples, each example is a vector of 64 floats
- second with labels, each label is an int within range (0,..,SIZE) (SIZE is 100) and it describes a class.

Both files are quire large and I can't fit them into memory so I've used tf.Dataset. I create two Datasets (one for features and one for labels) and them merge them using tf.data.Dataset.zip().
However during training I have "IndexError: list index out of range" error. 
But when I print input data it looks fine.
This is the code:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(SIZE, activation='softmax'))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad()
model.compile(optimizer=opt, 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#read data to: data and label
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((data, label))
#iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
#next_element = iterator.get_next()
#print(next_element[0])
#print("\n\n")
#print(next_element[1])

model.fit(dataset, epochs=50)
```

The error message is:

```
Epoch 1/50
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-129-f200a4503ff9>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/ai/collab-filter/dan.py', wdir='D:/ai/collab-filter')

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/ai/myModel.py", line 256, in <module>
    model.fit(dataset, epochs=50)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 694, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1433, in fit_generator
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 256, in model_iteration
    batch_size = int(nest.flatten(batch_data)[0].shape[0])

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 868, in __getitem__
    return self._dims[key]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I uncomment printing of the example I get (for me it looks good):

```
(<tf.Tensor: id=281899, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0011093982>, <tf.Tensor: id=281900, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.008290171>, <tf.Tensor: id=281901, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.010696268>, <tf.Tensor: id=281902, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.0068962937>, <tf.Tensor: id=281903, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0020472356>, <tf.Tensor: id=281904, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0041239075>, <tf.Tensor: id=281905, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.0018036675>, <tf.Tensor: id=281906, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.007521228>, <tf.Tensor: id=281907, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.012179799>, <tf.Tensor: id=281908, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.008569455>, <tf.Tensor: id=281909, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.005547243>, <tf.Tensor: id=281910, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.024963537>, <tf.Tensor: id=281911, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.0047834134>, <tf.Tensor: id=281912, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.0073425>, <tf.Tensor: id=281913, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.0049664816>, <tf.Tensor: id=281914, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0012769673>, <tf.Tensor: id=281915, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.008846987>, <tf.Tensor: id=281916, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.002845391>, <tf.Tensor: id=281917, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.0012304187>, <tf.Tensor: id=281918, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.0073605254>, <tf.Tensor: id=281919, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.019149099>, <tf.Tensor: id=281920, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0053162603>, <tf.Tensor: id=281921, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.00018294304>, <tf.Tensor: id=281922, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.007135446>, <tf.Tensor: id=281923, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.019139009>, <tf.Tensor: id=281924, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0031176396>, <tf.Tensor: id=281925, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.016997647>, <tf.Tensor: id=281926, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.017783713>, <tf.Tensor: id=281927, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.0033694915>, <tf.Tensor: id=281928, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.02030162>, <tf.Tensor: id=281929, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.01870913>, <tf.Tensor: id=281930, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.0057595233>, <tf.Tensor: id=281931, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.013816875>, <tf.Tensor: id=281932, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.00463876>, <tf.Tensor: id=281933, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.023181098>, <tf.Tensor: id=281934, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0064159813>, <tf.Tensor: id=281935, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.0018356718>, <tf.Tensor: id=281936, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.014198529>, <tf.Tensor: id=281937, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.019970264>, <tf.Tensor: id=281938, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.013106668>, <tf.Tensor: id=281939, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.01739781>, <tf.Tensor: id=281940, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.0075084846>, <tf.Tensor: id=281941, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.007515852>, <tf.Tensor: id=281942, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.008860749>, <tf.Tensor: id=281943, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.011078904>, <tf.Tensor: id=281944, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0031385398>, <tf.Tensor: id=281945, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.00069636817>, <tf.Tensor: id=281946, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.016473386>, <tf.Tensor: id=281947, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.010464343>, <tf.Tensor: id=281948, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.009564337>, <tf.Tensor: id=281949, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.00023193806>, <tf.Tensor: id=281950, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.0043777116>, <tf.Tensor: id=281951, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0033248402>, <tf.Tensor: id=281952, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0020942744>, <tf.Tensor: id=281953, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.00989055>, <tf.Tensor: id=281954, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.000547247>, <tf.Tensor: id=281955, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.0011691392>, <tf.Tensor: id=281956, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.033643395>, <tf.Tensor: id=281957, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.0014932752>, <tf.Tensor: id=281958, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.012660088>, <tf.Tensor: id=281959, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0124913>, <tf.Tensor: id=281960, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.010591994>, <tf.Tensor: id=281961, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.030872872>, <tf.Tensor: id=281962, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.0014752604>)



tf.Tensor(
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0], shape=(100,), dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue. Like I said before, I'm new in TensorFlow and I wasn't aware that the result of `tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset()` (I use it to read my data) can't be used directly to train the model. The result is in the form of a tuple of 64 Tensors, but now I'm aware that the training example has to have at least 2 dimensions (the first one can be 1), when the first dimension is the batch_size and the second is the size of the example itself. In my code the first Tensor (for example `<tf.Tensor: id=281899, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0011093982>`) was treated as the first training example, so its shape was () which caused the error. 
When I was trying to fix the problem I changed some things, that caused other error, which led me to the solution. Each example has to be resized. 
This is my current version of function to read training examples (DATA_SIZE is 64):

```
def expMap(*item) :
   item2 = tf.reshape(item, [1, DATA_SIZE])
   return item2

def generate_trainExp(nameD):
   filename = os.path.join(DATA, "exps{}.txt".format(nameD))
   record_defaults = [tf.float32] * DATA_SIZE
   dataset = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(filename, record_defaults, field_delim=' ')
   dataset = dataset.map(expMap)
   return dataset

.....
data = generate_trainExp(filename)
```

In `expMap()` the input item can be also transformed to vector of 64 floats before the reshape instruction (`item = tf.convert_to_tensor(item, dtype=tf.float32)`).